# Infinity loop with many to many in kotlin with subtable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I have a problem with a Many to Many relation.

Here I'll paste a code

**User.kt**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "USER", schema = "public")
 data class User(
    @JsonView(Views.Base::class)
    var username: String,
    @JsonView(Views.UserExtended::class)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    var projects: List<UserProject>? = mutableListOf()
```

**UserProject.kt**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "USER_PROJECT", schema = "public")
data class UserProject(
    @JsonView(Views.ProjectExtended::class)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    val user: User?,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    val project: Project?,
    @JsonView(Views.ProjectExtended::class)
    val projectRole: String
) : BaseEntity() {}
```

**Project.kt**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "PROJECT", schema = "public")
data class Project (
    @JsonView(Views.Base::class)
    val name: String?,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonView(Views.ProjectExtended::class)
    var users: List<UserProject>?
) : BaseEntity() {}
```

And i'm Going throught infinity loop. 
What I've done is simply doing a Views to overcome a problem. But I'm also using QueryDSL on @RepositoryRestResource which give me auto predicate on url's
And the problem is, I cannot simply add a **@Jsonview** To RepositoryRestResource interface.

I've tried doing a Projection but it gave me the result of Infinity loop cuz the **@JsonView** doesnt work on Projection and interface

Does someone have a suggestion how could I overcome this problem?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using Lombok with Kotlin? Data classes already have all you need

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Where is the error thrown? Also paste stack trace.